# Dropdown selected value isn't getting selected, it always shows the first value in selection

Tags: jquery

I have two dropdowlists ddprojecttype and ddprojectname. On selecting project type I'm populating projectnames into ddprojectname with jQuery and AJAX. It's showing properly only.

However, whenever I am trying to make a selection on the dropdownlist it always selects the first item. And also it's behaviour is peculiar: while I am viewing the aspx page in the browser then it's showing all the project names into the dropdown. Whereas in case of viewing the source it's not showing the dropdown options at all.

I will post the page code as well as the html for that and the jQery scripts for them:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddProjectTypeID" runat="server" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddProjectName" runat="server"  >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The jQuery for the scripts which loads the project names successfully is:

```
$('[id*="ddProjectTypeID"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).find(":selected").text() != "--Select--") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'Services/Service.asmx/GetProjectNames',
            data: '{"p_type_id":"' + $(this).find(":selected").val() + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                if (textStatus == "success") {
                    var myObject = data.d;
                    $('[id*="ddProjectName"] >option').remove();
                    $('[id*="ddProjectName"]').append($('<option></option>').val("--Select--").html("--Select--"));
                    for (var i = 0; i <= myObject.length - 1; i++) {
                        $('[id*="ddProjectName"]').append($('<option></option>').val(myObject[i].project_id)
                                        .html(myObject[i].project_name));
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(data, textStatus) {
                alert('An error has occured retrieving data!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It loads the names successfully onto the ddprojectnames dropdownlist:

Curiously whenever I am executing this code :

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ScheduleDetails scdetails = new ScheduleDetails();
    scdetails.ProjectTypeID = ddProjectTypeID.SelectedItem.Value;
            scdetails.ProjectID = ddProjectName.SelectedItem.Value;


}
```

it only gets scdetails.ProjectTypeID = 1 but 
scdetails.ProjectID = "--Select--"

I am not getting the reason why. Although I have loaded the projectnames from the cascading dropdown from projecttypeID even then also it gets "--select--" as result whenever irrespective I chose any value from ddprojectname ...

Why is this happening?

Comment: just a hunch- try commenting-out the line which populates the '----select---' option. What is the selected value now?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that because the list items of ddDropDownName are dependent on the selection of the ID dropdown, that the selected value cannot get set in the client lifecycle possibly because available data does not exist yet.

Try setting an event in the PreRender phase of your page and inspect the selected value of your drop down.  If it is set correctly there then that tells me that it is a problem loading this value into the dropdown from ViewState.

Comment: @maple lemme check it out within few minutes . its really troublesome. although this shouldnt have happnd ... cause the flow of the dropdowns goes like this : 
1. Select Project Type id 
2. Project Type ID is send to the Webservice :
3. Webservice populates the ddprojectnames via ajax.
4. the dropdown shows all the names having projectTypeId = '1' 
5. I try to select ProjectID 
6. Now i Click The button Which Assigns the ProjectID to  scdetails.ProjectID = ddProjectName.SelectedItem.Value

Comment: Perhaps you should try to crawl before you walk.  It is clear that the ViewState is not updating correctly on the server side after the postback.  To create the simplest scenario you should populate the ddProjectName dropdownlist from a server side event invoking a postback within an update panel.  You should be able to move the business logic within the javascript ajax call to a server side event and then see if that makes any difference in populating your ViewState.  If so then the problem is located in your javascript ajax call somewhere.

Comment: @maple yes with due respect i agree to that . i hav already succeeded in doing tht what actually u meant by doing it from the server side event.. i guess u know d reason why we dont use ajax update panel.. because of its heavy viewstate. even i am aware of that possibility due to client side interactions the viewstate isnt getting populated from the jquery ajax call . that is why i am trying to find out why the above incident is happening . cause i am clueless why its not happening cause from serer side events its perfectly fine to the logic i have described and the scenario i implemented :)

Comment: @maple one more interesting point i wd like to tell you. if i havent set EnableEventValidation="false" its giving error while i am using this ajax. is this the really d case where the viewstate isnt getting populated properly?

Comment: Based on the information I have, I don't see a reason why this the selected <option> is not getting updated to ViewState.  I also understand why you don't like Update panels.  My only guess at this point is that somewhere there might be a javascript error happening before the ViewState gets updated before the postback.  Look very carefully and turn all javascript error reporting on to verify this.  Otherwise I might workaround this by using a javascript to update the value of a hidden input field on selection change of your dropdown.  In the Click server side event you can get the value then.

Comment: So you are suppressing EventValidation messages?  What are the errors you receive, this is probably the issue.

Comment: @maple yep actually the problem is i am adding values via jquery ajax not the problem is asp.net viewstate doesnt knows that there are new values added to the dropdown hence its giving errors if i dont suppress event validation. however if i suppress the event validation. the problem stated above is the thing which i faced . however d error which i am getting is :Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page

Answer (score 0):

Would you try :

```
$("#<%=ddProjectTypeID.ClientID %>") instead of $('[id*="ddProjectTypeID"]')
```

The ID of the DrpDwnList might be changed in the client side if you're using a master page or something.

Comment: the selector $('[id*="ddProjectTypeID"]') is working just fine.and i cant use that caz its an external Js file.even though it shouldnt make too much of diffrence.cause i am already getting to see the ddprojectnames populated in the page but the html source is just showing as : <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$ddProjectName" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ddProjectName" style="color:Gray;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;width:203px;">
 <option selected="selected" value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
after i select the projectTypeId from the ajax code which populates the ddprojectname

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact above what I did is something interesting which I haven't came across earlier.

For an instance I have wrote what my problem was. Basically it's the postback error which occurs when you click and select an option from JavaScript, so what you can do is:

Create a custom control which is based on extending the `System.Web.Ui.WebControls.Dropdownlist`, and instead of using `<asp:dropdownlist>` just use that.

Here is the code for that for custom class:

```
 public class DropDown:System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
{
}
```

To the reference I would give you a very good blog post for that which actually has dealt with this problem which quite didn't help out with my original problem.

[Postback Error Blog](http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/cascadingdropdown-casues-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-error/#comment-286)

But I could actually figure out what was the problem. Basically what happens is when I populate a dropdownlist with a jQuery AJAX on a cascading effect. The viewstate actually doesn't gets updated, so as a result when I click a button for postback it gives the error as:

```
nvalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page
```

Now to avoid that I have already given the link.

Now to solve the problem how to get the value. For that I have put an hiddenfield for the page for the cascading dropdown and have set its value to dropdowns selected value to hiddenfield. Now on button click I can get the actual value from the dropdown (which is basically a custom control) like :

```
$('[id*="btnSubmit"]').click(function() {
    $('[id*="hf"]').val($('[id*="ddProjectName"]').find("selected").val());
});

Note: You cannot do the textbox1.text = ddcustom.selectedvalue
```

and now you can access the value from button as like:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { String Project_id= hf.value;  }
```

It's because the viewstate doesn't provide with the client side data which has been changed from cascading effect from jQuery AJAX.